# Lists within repeating structure

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I need to write the repeating structure data into named lists. The name of the list needs to be determined in the variable i.
I have the following input data:

| Nome | Local | Hora |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Thiago | Cantina | 08:01 |
| Ana | Cantina | 08:05 |
| Thiago | Cantina | 08:10 |
| Thiago | Sala01 | 08:50 |
| Jose | Sala01 | 09:03 |
| Thiago | Sala01 | 09:30 |
| Jose | Sala01 | 09:45 |
| Jose | Cantina | 09:49 |
| Ana | Biblioteca | 11:07 |

Code:

```
#Input
list_entry=[['Thiago', 'Cantina', '08:01:00'], ['Ana', 'Cantina', '08:05:00'], ['Thiago', 'Cantina', '08:10:00'], ['Thiago', 'Sala01', '08:50:00'], ['Jose', 'Sala01','09:03:00'], ['Thiago', 'Sala01', '09:30:00'], ['Jose', 'Sala01', '09:45:00'], ['Jose', 'Cantina', '09:49:00'], ['Ana', 'Biblioteca', '11:07:00']]


i=1
lista=[]
    while i <= 4:#repeticacao1
        y=0
        inicio, fim = intervalo[i] #interval is a dictionary with time period every 1 hour
        #The data of the block below must be written in a list with the name list1. After exiting While(#repeticacao2) and the i is incremented, the data must be written to a list named list2 and so on.
        while y < 6: #repeticacao2 - Stop condition is <6 due to the number of input registers
            registro2 = df_registro['Hora'].dt.time[y]
            if inicio <= registro2 < fim: # checks if time is between the start and end of the range
                print(f'O registro esta dentro do intervalo {inicio:%H:%M} às {fim:%H:%M}')
                #Create a list with Name and Location datal
                lista.append([df_registro['Nome'][y],df_registro['Local'][y]])
            y += 1
        i += 1
```

Result:

```
[['Thiago', 'Cantina'], ['Ana', 'Cantina'], ['Thiago', 'Cantina'], ['Thiago', 'Sala01'], ['Jose', 'Sala01'], ['Thiago', 'Sala01'], ['Jose', 'Sala01'], ['Jose', 'Cantina'], ['Ana', 'Biblioteca']]
```

The result is a list of all records. However, in this way, the time intervals are being mixed.

The expected result would be for separate time intervals. Thus:

```
list1 = [['Thiago', 'Cantina'], ['Ana', 'Cantina'], ['Thiago', 'Cantina'], ['Thiago', 'Sala01']]

list2 = [['Jose', 'Sala01'], ['Thiago', 'Sala01'], ['Jose', 'Sala01'], ['Jose', 'Cantina']]

list3 = []

list4 = ['Ana', 'Biblioteca']
```

I tried to create the list with list[i] and then with list[i].append but it doesn't work. How could it be done?

Comment: please include input data.

Comment: Why do you need to use named lists, instead of just using nested lists?

Comment: Sounds like you need a groupby

Comment: You are just appending entries to a single list.  If you wanted the outer list to have separate sublists, then you need to create a new list inside your `while` loop, append your entries to THAT list, and then append THAT list to the master `lista`.

Comment: @Alexander - Input data included

Comment: @Barmar - In the end I will need to count the number of connections within the time interval of each user. When I tried to use nested lists, I couldn't split the time intervals.

Comment: @MadPhysicist - Yes. I tried using: df_registro_test = pd.DataFrame(lista,columns=['Nome', 'Local', 'Hora']) 
df = df_registro_test.groupby(['Nome','Local']).count()

But that way I can't separate by the time interval.

Comment: Your final output has nothing to do with time interval. Could you please clarify the question?

Comment: @MadPhysicist - In the final output, list1 is the users of the first time interval (08:00 to 09:00). List2 is the users of the second time interval (09:00 to 10:00)... and so on. In List3 there is no record, because I don't have connections from 10:00 to 11:00.

Comment: @ThiagoRamos. That's not clear from the question. Please edit it. The expected output looks like it's categorized by room

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```
df["Hora"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Hora"])
d = df.set_index('Hora').resample('1H', label='right').sum()  #Inorder to get the Hourly index including 10 o'clock

#Here I am separating the sum string by capital latter and converting them
#into list by using .split()

import re
d['Nome'] = d['Nome'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r"\B([A-Z])", r" \1", str(x)))
d['Local'] = d['Local'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r"\B([A-Z])", r" \1", str(x)))

#lastly zipping both column list values and define a new column
d['List'] = d.apply(lambda x: [list(a) for a in zip(x.Nome.split(' '), x.Local.split(' '))], axis=1)
```

Print:

```
d['List'][0]    #Lets say the List1
```

Output:

```
[['Thiago', 'Cantina'],
 ['Ana', 'Cantina'],
 ['Thiago', 'Cantina'],
 ['Thiago', 'Sala01']]
```

And to get all list into one:

```
[[y for y in x if '0' not in y] for x in list(d.List)] #Here Looping just to avoid '0' at 10 o'clock
```

Output:

```
[[['Thiago', 'Cantina'],
  ['Ana', 'Cantina'],
  ['Thiago', 'Cantina'],
  ['Thiago', 'Sala01']],
 [['Jose', 'Sala01'],
  ['Thiago', 'Sala01'],
  ['Jose', 'Sala01'],
  ['Jose', 'Cantina']],
 [],
 [['Ana', 'Biblioteca']]]
```

UPDATE:

In order to lowercase the all list element:

Option 1:By add Lambada function

```
[[list((map(lambda x: x.lower(), y))) for y in x if '0' not in y] for x in list(d.List)]
```

Option 2: By for loop

```
[[[x.lower() for x in y] for y in x if '0' not in y] for x in list(d.List)]
```

Output:

```
[[['thiago', 'cantina'],
  ['ana', 'cantina'],
  ['thiago', 'cantina'],
  ['thiago', 'sala01']],
 [['jose', 'sala01'],
  ['thiago', 'sala01'],
  ['jose', 'sala01'],
  ['jose', 'cantina']],
 [],
 [['ana', 'biblioteca']]]
```

Comment: @Thiago Ramos Please check above code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The code worked perfectly as shown in the example.
Have a second question:
With an entry with the "Nome" field in all lowercase, what would be the alternative?

Comment: Hi @ThiagoRamos you mean you willing to have all list values in lowercase, am I right?

Comment: Yes that's right!

Comment: @ThiagoRamos please check the update

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use a while loop here? It seems like a good case for comprehensions.

Something along the lines of

```
hourly_list = [entry for entry in entry_list if interval_start <= entry.time < interval_end]
```

would give you the list of entries within a given interval (I haven't quite used the data structure you're working with but the method should work).

Answer (score 0):

Creating a separate variable for each location is counter-productive. Instead, consider using a dictionary keyed by location:

```
{k: list(g['Nome']) for k, g in df.groupby('Local')}
```